How to Upper Bound the Spectral Norm of $\left(XX^T\right)^{-1}\left(XX^T\right)^{-1}X$?
I have an observation matrix $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Considering $XX^T$, this matrix can be seen as a correlation matrix between individuals, so it generally has elements close to the identity matrix $I$ (actually $n$ times the identity matrix). What I want to study here is the spectral norm of $(XX^T)^{-1}(XX^T)^{-1}X$.
If $XX^T$ were $nI$, this spectral norm would be something like $\frac{1}{n^2} \lambda_{\text{max}}$ (where $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $X$ ). However, in practice, $XX^T$ is very close to $nI$ but not exactly. Thus, I am looking for a way to effectively upper bound this norm.

By a singular value decompositon of $X$, one easily sees that the singular values of the matrix in question are $\sigma_i(X)^{-3}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Hence the spectral norm of the matrix is $\sigma_\min(X)^{-3}$.
